# Assign a random class different to every img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now this code gives all the imgs the same random class.

How can I give at each image a different random class?

Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    bgImageTotal = 5;
    randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (bgImageTotal - 1)) + 1;
    $('img').addClass('img' + randomNumber);
});
```

```css
.img1{max-height:10px}
.img2{max-height:40px}
.img3{max-height:70px}
.img4{max-height:100px}
.img5{max-height:130px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each img to have unique random class, you can create an array from a set:

```js
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    var $imgs = $('img');
    var len = $imgs.length;
    
    var set = new Set;
    while (set.size != len) {
        set.add((Math.random() * len | 0) + 1);
    }
    var arr = [...set];
    $imgs.each(function(pos) { $(this).addClass('img' + arr[pos]) });
});
```

```css
.img1{height:10px}
.img2{height:40px}
.img3{height:70px}
.img4{height:100px}
.img5{height:130px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Guedes!

Comment: Glad to see it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop, generate random, assign:

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    var bgImageTotal = 5;
    $('img').each(function() {
        var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (bgImageTotal - 1)) + 1;
        $(this).addClass('img' + randomNumber);
    });
});
```

Your issue was `$('img')` will return all the images - after that, you have to loop them and assign the class to each one individually.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you only generate a single random number and apply it to all the images. Instead, provide a function to the `addClass()` method which will then loop over each matched element and generate a random number in each iteration.

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  bgImageTotal = 5;
  $('img').addClass(function() {
    return 'img' + (Math.round(Math.random() * (bgImageTotal - 1)) + 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.img1 { max-height: 10px; }
.img2 { max-height: 40px; }
.img3 { max-height: 70px; }
.img4 { max-height: 100px; }
.img5 { max-height: 130px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, don't forget using loop, that's the only thing you missing there, you can use simple javascript loop like for loop or use jQuery each if you already using jQuery, try this and should all work:

your CSS:

```
.img1{max-height:10px}
.img2{max-height:40px}
.img3{max-height:70px}
.img4{max-height:100px}
.img5{max-height:130px}
```

your HTML:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YeDYzSR.png">
```

and you Js(jQuery):

```
"use strict";
  $(document).ready(function(){
  // in jQuery, you can select by ID, Class, Tag, etc... this a tag selector, selecting all <img> tag on your page 
    $('img').each(function(i, e) {
       var imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1);
         $(this).addClass('img' + imgNo);
    });
  });
```

All working, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign function wraps the argument element tag into a jQuery object that contains all the img elements along with special jQuery method which calls a function on each of the jQuery collection passing in the index of the element and the dom element. To use .addClass on the dom element. It must be wrapped in a jQuery collection.
To assign individual elements, use the jQuery .each method.

```
    $('img).each(function(index, element){
      $(element).addClass('img' + randomNumber);
    })
```